# How to get http get request sending domain in angular2

Tags: angular

How to get http get request sending domain in angular2
we are using 
 `let product_id = this.route.snapshot.queryParams["name"];`
 this code for get get parameters and how to get domain name that the request sending

Comment: you want domain name from url ???

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {
    let url = document.location.protocol +'//'+ document.location.hostname + ':my_port' );
}
```

Comment: How could you delete my comment?? Is it possible to delete someone's comment on StackOverflow, strange !!

Comment: @PardeepJain - you can flag it if you find not appropriate ..and moderator delete if you proven true

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `Document` by angular, you can simply get it using `window` object like this

```
constructor(private window: Window, private router: Router) {
   let hostname = this.window.location.hostname;
}
```

if You want to get URL path name you can get using `router` instance like this -

```
this.router.url
```

So you can get a whole domain name with path and params by concatenating the values you required.